# How to replace values in a 4-dimensional array?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy, multidimensional-array

Let's say I have a 4D array that is

```
(600, 1, 3, 3)
```

If you take the first 2 elements they may look like this:

```
0 1 0
1 1 1
0 1 0

2 2 2
3 3 3
1 1 1

etc
```

I have a list that contains certain weights that I want to ***replace*** specific values in the array. My intention is to use the index of the list element match the value in the array. Therefore, this list

```
[0.1  1.1  1.2  1.3]
```

when applied against my array would give this result:

```
0.1   1.1   0.1
1.1   1.1   1.1
0.1   1.1   0.1

1.2   1.2   1.2
1.3   1.3   1.3
1.1   1.1   1.1

etc
```

This method would have to run through the entire 600 elements of the array.

I can do this in a clunky way using a `for` loop and `array[array==x] = y` or `np.place` but I wanted to avoid a loop and perhaps use a method that at once will replace all values.  Is there such an approach?

Comment: Simply index into the array version : `np.asarray(vals)[idx]`, where `vals` is the list and `idx` are those `4D` indices? Or use `np.take(vals, idx)` to do the array conversion under the hoods.

Comment: this may work, but how do you apply it to the 4D array?

Comment: I just told you that - `idx` is the `4D` array of indices.

Comment: beautiful, works exactly as I needed, if you have time to add as an answer I'll choose it, thx

Comment: I would encourage you to post an answer based on your findings. Feel free to use the code from comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoting from @Divakar's solution in the comments, which solves the issue in a very efficient manner:

> Simply index into the array version: 
>   `np.asarray(vals)[idx]`, where `vals` is
>   the list and `idx` is the array.
>   Or use `np.take(vals, idx)` to do the array conversion under the hood.